# Get Current and Previous level In Hive QL

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table with below details. I need to get the Current level and Previous level.

```
ID   Level       start_dt                End_dt  
A      1         2018-03-12 18:39:10     2020-01-01 00:00:00   
A      1         2018-01-17 13:21:26     2018-03-12 18:39:10  
A      2         2018-01-14 13:21:17     2018-01-17 13:21:26
```

My End state table is as below:
ID, current_level, previous_level, upgrade/downgrade flag

I tried ranking based on END_dt desc. But it would rank my second row as 2 and that isn't the previous level. Can I handle this in a single query? Or a single hop?

Answer (score 0):

Tricky part is the previous level, I don't think that's possible in 1 pass.  Try something like this though

`with setup AS (
select ID
        , Level
        , row_number() over (partition by ID order by End_dt desc) as row_num
        , MIN(Level) over (Partition by ID order by End_dt desc ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) as previous_level
from my_table
)
SELECT ID
        , Level
        , previous_level
        , case when Level = previous_level THEN 'No Upgrade/Downgrade'
                WHEN Level < previous_level THEN 'Upgrade'
                WHEN Level > previous_level THEN 'Downgrade'
                ELSE 'Unknown' END AS upgrade_downgrade_description
FROM    setup 
WHERE   row_num = 1
;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LAG to get the previous row values, reference docs [LAG](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics#LanguageManualWindowingAndAnalytics-LAGspecifyingalagof3rowsanddefaultvalueof0)

```
create table table_1(ID string,Level int,start_dt timestamp,End_dt timestamp);

insert into table_1 values
('A',1,'2018-03-12 18:39:10','2020-01-01 00:00:00'),
('A',1,'2018-01-17 13:21:26','2018-03-12 18:39:10'),
('A',2,'2018-01-14 13:21:17','2018-01-17 13:21:26');
```

SQL:

```
select id,curr_level,prev_level,
case when curr_level=prev_level then 'No Ups - Downs'
when curr_level>prev_level then 'Downgrade'
when curr_level<prev_level then 'Up-Downgrade'
when prev_level is null then 'No-Previous Level'
else 'Unkonwn state'
end upgrade_downgrade_description
from(
select table_1.id,
table_1.level as curr_level,
lag(table_1.level,1) over (partition by table_1.id order by table_1.end_dt desc) prev_level
from table_1) s;
```

Output:

```
id  curr_level  prev_level  upgrade_downgrade_description
A   1           NULL        No-Previous Level
A   1           1           No Ups - Downs
A   2           1           Downgrade
```